# Not able to read values from .env file

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, environment-variables, web3storage

```js
//accessToken.mjs
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import { Web3Storage } from "web3.storage";

function getAccessToken() {
  // WEB3STORAGE_TOKEN environment variable before you run your code.
  console.log(process.env.WEB3STORAGE_TOKEN);
  return process.env.WEB3STORAGE_TOKEN;
}
getAccessToken();
function makeStorageClient() {
  return new Web3Storage({ token: getAccessToken() });
}
export default makeStorageClient;
```

running the command below

```bash
$ node .\accessToken.mjs
undefined
```

I added a `.env` file in the root directory and didn't use any quote or semicolon. I am still not able to get the `WEB3STORAGE_TOKEN` value.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

I don't know how you are working with other files but if you want to use import statements in NodeJs you need to add `type` attribute inside `package.json` like so:

```
"type": "module"
```

and in your code file use import like this

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env.TEST);
```

You can see here in [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-zvedqd)

---

Just put this on the top

```
require("dotenv").config()
```

Instead of

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

Comment: it gave me this  "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead" error

Answer (score 0):

Actually the file in which I called the environment variable is inside another directory and my .env file was in the root. So defining config({path:"/some/.env"})
path solves my problem